# Best way to retrieve values from lots of Winform controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a project that required me to design a form with a lot of text fields and a few buttons. Because of Visual Studio's auto-generated code, I have about 150+ text fields that I need to be able to get the value from in a class separate from the form.

Part of the form is that there are tabs each containing similar layouts, but there are minor differences in between them. Because of the way tabs work, I have to have different names for each of the fields shared between tabs, rather than being able to access that field relative to the specified tab. This is what has led to so many form controls.

My question is this... currently I am working on a class to allow me to take the value from all of these text fields and run a string replace on a document template (a Word XML file) to overwrite placeholders with the values in the related text fields. Is there a more efficient way to do this than just creating an accessor method for each member of the form and using it to pass the value to the string.Replace() method?

I'm new to C#, so this was the only way I could think of to approach the problem.

Comment: It sounds like your data would be better placed in a DataGrid than creating 150+ text boxes. Are you tied to WinForms or would switching to WPF be an option? In any case you don't need to create accessors for each control - just access them via `TextBox1.Text` etc. (or whatever the name of your controls is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update all textbox controls in bulk for your WinForm application.

Luckily WinForm controls are mostly derived from the Control class which offers the .Name and .Text of a Control object.

You could do that using this code:

```
// Loop through all controls in the form
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
   if(control is TextBox)
   {
      // DO WORK
   }
}
```

You can gain access to the Name or Text within the loop by calling `control.Text` or `control.Name`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Worth noting that if TextBox specific fields are required, use (control as TextBox) in order to access them. After checking that it is a TextBox of course.

Comment: By "name", do you mean it returns a string with the name of the variable that textbox is associated with?

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau - yes exactly. Let's say you drag and drop a textbox control from the Toolbox which defaults to "textbox1" `control.Name` will return "textbox1". Similarly, if the value of the textbox is "Hello World" then `control.Text` will return "Hello World".

Comment: Thought so. I originally wanted to do this, and was looking into ways to get a string of the variable name. I should have realized the name field was accessible. I'm still not sure what the best way would be to go through them all. Thanks though!

Comment: If you need further help, please post your code and I can always refine my answer to clarify further steps.